# Clear Marker on Google Map when change location of dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

all. Please help me solve this issue. Currently I have a dropdown of multiple location for google map. But the marker keeps on duplicating when I change the location. Here is the code for google map. I would like the map to clear the previous marker and only display marker on the current selected location

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
function initMap() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(4.2105,101.9758),
      zoom: 6.5
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
}

function geocodeAddress(location) {
    var address = '';

    if (location != 'all') {
        var resultFromAjax = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('getLocation') }}",
            data: {
                id: location
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.location != '') {
                    address = response.location;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
    else {
        address = 'Malaysia';
    }

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            console.log(marker)
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
      });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you set `async` to `false` so that the AJAX function returns a value BEFORE trying to perform the GeoCoding?

Comment: Also - how are you actually calling the `geocodeAddress` function?

Comment: Is the ajax call intended to return a location from your database ( or elsewhere ) and for that location to then be used in the `geocodeAddress` function as the input parameter?

Comment: Where is the variable/input parameter `location` defined?

Comment: I have set async to false. The geocode funtion is in controller

Comment: By the ways, thank you for reminding me all the things above, I have found the solution 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, instead of locally declare the marker, I set it as a global function before populate it based on location using geocoding.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
function initMap() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(4.2105,101.9758),
      zoom: 6.5
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //Marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker();
    marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
    marker.setMap(map);
    //

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
}

function geocodeAddress(location) {
    var address = '';

    if (location != 'all') {
        var resultFromAjax = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('getLocation') }}",
            data: {
                id: location
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.location != '') {
                    address = response.location;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
    else {
        address = 'Malaysia';
    }

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker.setOptions({
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: results[0].geometry.location  
          });
            // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            //   map: map,
            //   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            //   position: results[0].geometry.location
            // });

            console.log(marker)
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
      });
}
```